# Avoid creating BigQuery table if nothing to write

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

This is my code to write rows to a new BigQuery table:

```java
PCollection<TableRow> lhReports = results.get(BigQueryImport.LIGHTHOUSE_TAG);
lhReports.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
         .named("write-lighthouse")
         .to(getBigQueryOutput(options, "lighthouse"))
         .withSchema(lhReportSchema)
         .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
         .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));
```

Half of the time my pipeline will not have any rows to write, but the tables will be created regardless. **I'd like to ensure that I don't create any empty tables.**

The first thing I checked was how `CREATE_IF_NEEDED` works. It just specifies that the table can be created if it doesn't already exist. There is no other `CreateDisposition` enum that depends on the output length.

I'm not super sophisticated with Dataflow, so my next thought was to wrap the pipeline in a condition that first checks the size of the `PCollection`, `lhReports`. But I'm not seeing any kind of size/length methods in the [API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/values/PCollection).

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Half of the time my pipeline will not have any rows to write"? Is the data source of the pipeline bounded or unbounded? There might be some misunderstanding of the Apache Beam model. You can't really "wrap" the pipeline and check the size of the `PCollection`. Implementing a pipeline in Apache Beam only defines what the pipeline will look like during execution; there no actual runtime context so you can't get the size/length of a `PCollection`.

Comment: @Andrew I'm using v1.9 so I don't think Beam is necessarily involved, if that matters. Here's the context of the code for clarification: https://github.com/HTTPArchive/bigquery/blob/master/dataflow/java/src/main/java/com/httparchive/dataflow/BigQueryImport.java#L478-L484. Is there any kind of transform I could write that can abort the pipeline?

Comment: Apache Beam is the successor to Dataflow 1.x. The concepts and programming model of Apache Beam still apply. There is no such thing as applying a transform that will "abort" the pipeline - this doesn't exist in the Beam programming model. If you upgrade to Apache Beam 2.x, you may be able to redesign the pipeline using filtering/partitioning and `DynamicDestinations` to avoid creating tables unnecessarily. Reference: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html.